# Exponential equation, soliving for x

Tags: exponential-function

The actual problem is:

$$e^{2x} - 3e^x = 10$$

I want to just natural log both sides, but I don't know if that's the right approach. I don't think that I can distribute an $\ln$, right?

Comment: right. Instead, $e^x-3e^x = -2e^x$ so $-2e^x=10$. Now why can't you take natural log yet?

Comment: Did you intend $3e^x$ or $(3e)^x$?

Comment: I just edited it. It was suppose to be e^(2x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $e^{2x} = (e^x)^2$, you can write this as a quadratic. Let $y = e^x$. Then it reduces to solving
$$
y^2 - 3y - 10 = 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't see that.